# Docusign PHP SDK resending envelope with Demo Account updates the envelope but no email is sent

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am trying to resend an existing envelope that a user may have mislaid or otherwise not received. The API is updating the envelope with the request, but is not resending the email. I am receiving a 200 OK response from the api. This is my call;

```
$envelopeApi->update($account_id, $env_id, json_encode([resend_envelope => true]));
```

The logs show the call is successful;

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net:7801/restapi/v2/accounts/eb84945a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-125dae50be01/envelopes/1e748673-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d932f6bdb90e
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 24
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/2.0.1/php
X-DocuSign-SDK: PHP
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 

{"resend_envelope":true}

200 OK

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 60
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 3f4d4386-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ede4199f7f35

{
  "envelopeId": "1e748673-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d932f6bdb90e"
}
```

I have read all the threads I can find on SO and none seem to cover my experience. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: this should work, I am not sure why you don't see another email. Can you try to triple check this? change to a different email provider, set a simple envelope with a single signer, maybe even create a new developer account. Before we jump to open a bug, I just want to ensure there's nothing you missed.

Comment: @Inbar thank you for your response. I have created a new envelope using a gmail account and only a single document as suggested. I received the original envelope, but when I resend as above it is not received. However I get a 200 ok and can see the envelope is sent in history.

Comment: @Inbar Gazit - I have now tested this in a live environment with exactly the same code and the experience is the same. I can send the initial envelope but when I resend it it is not received, although it says its sent in history and I get a 200 ok. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this post, this is how to resend an envelope using v2 of the PHP SDK, as provided by dev support. Its a shame the SDK isn't better documented.

```
$options = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi\UpdateOptions();
$options ->setResendEnvelope("True");
$results = $envelopeApi->update(self::$accountID, $envelopeid, "{}", $options);
```

Thanks to Edwin@DS